# How do I convert rows with 45 columns into 15 separate rows, each with 3 columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

I am working with a google sheet that gets data from an email parser. Each time an email comes in, a single row is created, and fills in these columns:

`B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO, AP, AQ`.

I'd like to have it output as:

```
B1  | C1  | D1

E1  | F1  | G1
....

AO1 | AP1 | AQ1

B2  | C2  | D2
....
```

Is this possible?
I've tried using this:

`=FILTER({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!D:D;Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!G:G;Sheet1!H:H,Sheet1!I:I,Sheet1!J:J;Sheet1!K:K,Sheet1!L:L,Sheet1!M:M;Sheet1!N:N,Sheet1!O:O,Sheet1!P:P;Sheet1!Q:Q,Sheet1!R:R,Sheet1!S:S;Sheet1!T:T,Sheet1!U:U,Sheet1!V:V;Sheet1!W:W,Sheet1!X:X,Sheet1!Y:Y;Sheet1!Z:Z,Sheet1!AA:AA,Sheet1!AB:AB;Sheet1!AC:AC,Sheet1!AD:AD,Sheet1!AE:AE;Sheet1!AF:AF,Sheet1!AG:AG,Sheet1!AH:AH;Sheet1!AI:AI,Sheet1!AJ:AJ,Sheet1!AK:AK;Sheet1!AL:AL,Sheet1!AM:AM,Sheet1!AN:AN;Sheet1!AO:AO,Sheet1!AP:AP,Sheet1!AQ:AQ},LEN(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A))`

But it was just based on another answer I saw on here, and I am sure that I am not applying the `filter(range,len())` part correctly.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] "But it was just a based on another answer..." add a  link to the referred "another answer".

Comment: Would you please explain how the numeric suffix is determined?

Comment: The data is input into the row in three categories: Name, Type, and Info, and then repeats. So the 45 columns are just going Name, Type, Info, Name (new group), Type, Info, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You have a cell containing exactly 45 comma-separated values. Your goal is to split those values, add a suffix for the row number, and then list the values in rows of three - that is, in 45 cells (3 columns wide, 15 rows deep).

Use this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(split(transpose(SPLIT(Query(transpose(split(REGEXREPLACE($C$2&",",",",""&$B$2&","),", ",1,1))&","&if(MOD(row(indirect((address($B$7,$B$6)&":"&address($B$9,$B$6))))-row(indirect(address($B$7-1,$B$6))),$B$3)=0,"|",""),,9^9),"|")),",")))`

---

**Example output**

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Props:**

infoinspired.com: [Split a Column into Multiple N Columns in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-column-into-multiple-n-columns-sheets/)

Other similar formulas:

- [Split 1 column into multiple columns with up to 500 cells each](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787543/1330560)
- [Split data from one column into multiple columns and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55768470/1330560)

---

**UPDATE**

Values are already in 45 columns; no initial split is required.

**Revised formula**

`=arrayformula(trim(split(transpose(split(query(transpose(indirect(address($A$6,$A$8)&":"&address($A$6,$A$10-1)))&A6&","&if(MOD(row(indirect((address($A$22,$A$20)&":"&address($A$24,$A$20))))-row(indirect(address($A$22-1,$A$20))),$A$2)=0,"|",""),,9^9),"|")),",")))`

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Refer my update.